# Cannot undo (Your changes to the files were overwritten by other users)

Tags: android-studio

This Happens when i'm in the XML editor:

[image: 1]

And when i'm in the Java editor it just wont work and the option from the Edit menu is grayed out (same with Redo)
tried opening the file location in the file manager but it couldnt find anything.

tried looking searching for it on google and did not find other pepole who have gotten the same problem.